# What's the proper syntax for strings in LIKE using cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to execute a query but I'm not sure how to make it search for strings. For example

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'blah%'')
```

This gives me a syntax error. Also if it's not obvious, I'm very new to python and oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're starting your string with `'` and want to use `'` inside your string, you either have to escape it using `\` or you can use a different quote to start your string:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE \'blah%\'') 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'blah%'") 
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'blah%'""")
```

Comment: @awesomebrownguy you will soon need to use bind variables: `cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM locations WHERE city LIKE :c', c = 'O%')`